# xCode 6 - Corrupt Breakpoints (Limited Variables / Chinese Characters)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

My xCode 6 Swift Project breakpoints don't seems to be working correctly.

When placing a breakpoint in any method the variables are either blank or populated with Chinese characters (see below).

I believe there must be a corruption with my target because earlier today I ran my Today Widget and this works correctly and can see the variables and contents BUT when running my main target I get what you see in the image below.

Please help this is driving me mad!!!

[image]

Comment: Note: I do not have a localized string file for Chinese. I have 1 localisable.strings file for English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone getting the same issue / coming across this stack post. I fixed the issue by changing the Optimization Level all to None instead of "Fastest, Smallest [-Os]".